# Static IP addresses for host and guest VMs on RHEL 7

Tags: networking, virtualization, redhat

I have RHEL 7 installed on a development server of ours that hosts two virtual machines, both RHEL 7.
I've set up a static IP address for the host that can access our network - I can SSH to the server and everything else.
Unsure how to set up the two virtual machines as though they too, are physical machines on our network, open for SSH and so on. Is this possible?

I've tried going into each VM and editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, multiple goes at creating virtual networks and network interfaces via the virtual machine manager.

I've looked at creating aliases of the host network although this seems frowned upon.

Ideal IP addresses:

- Host IP: 192.168.16.11
- VM 1: 192.168.16.12
- VM 2: 192.168.16.12

Current settings on host:

```sh
[root@host ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-host 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.16.11
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=192.168.16.201
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0-host
UUID=0764f192-8064-4673-8067-79d45e67bb81
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
```

```sh
[root@host ~]# ip route show
default via 192.168.16.201 dev eth0 proto static metric 101 
192.168.16.11 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.11 metric 101 
192.168.16.201 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 101
```

Please let me know if you require any extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure.
Are you using KVM(libvirt)?
You cannot have same ip address on 2 different machine on the same subnet.
You can use:

1. Host IP: 192.168.16.11/24(assign to bridge interface)
2. VM 1: 192.168.16.12/24
3. VM 2: 192.168.16.13/24

Are you made a bridge between physical interface and virtual NIC?
If you are using KVM you can configure it using cockpit or command line.

You have to attach interface to vm after create the bridge:

1. virsh attach-interface --domain "vmname" --type bridge --source "bridgename" --target "vmname"_nic --model virtio --persistent
2. virsh attach-interface --domain "vmname2" --type bridge --source "bridgename2" --target "vmname2"_nic --model virtio --persistent

Than you need to use "virsh edit vmname" to remove any other network interface.
[network structure images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QxXF.png)